# @FindBy cannot find an element, but findElement can find it at salesforce

Tags: java, maven, selenium-webdriver

I'm working with a BDD Maven Framework, testing with Selenium Webdriver a Salesforce application.

Furthermore, after few pages working well, I faced the following problem:

My PageFactory (Page package), is using the annotaion @FindBy, but Selenium cannot found a WebElement to interact, but I've created another project to test if driver.findElement(By.xpath... works and Selenium can find the WebElement easily.

With @FindBy, I receive the error:

```
[31morg.openqa.selenium.ElementNotInteractableException: element not interactable
```

I have another pages working with @FindBy without problems, using Relative or Absolute Xpath and works well, but specifically in this page, it doesn't work.
As you can see below I've tried to click with javascript and with a default method.

**Page Class:**

```
import org.openqa.selenium.support.FindBy;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.How;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory;

import Comgas.PoCProspect.util.driverContext;

public class EtapaC_DebitoPage {

    public EtapaC_DebitoPage() {
        PageFactory.initElements(driverContext.getDriver(), this);
    }


    @FindBy(how = How.XPATH, using = "//input[@type='checkbox'][@data-interactive-lib-uid='3']")
    protected WebElement checkBox;
```

**Action Class:**

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import aaa.PoCProspect.page.EtapaC_DebitoPage;
import aaa.PoCProspect.util.driverContext;

public class EtapaC_DebitoAction extends EtapaC_DebitoPage {


    protected void clickEditAutorizaDebtAutom() {
        //driverContext.getDriver().findElement(By.xpath("chkAutorizaDebtAutom")).click();
        chkAutorizaDebtAutom.click();
    }

}
```

**Step Definition Class:**

```
import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;
import aaa.PoCProspect.action.EtapaC_DebitoAction;
import aaa.PoCProspect.stepDef.util.util;
import aaa.PoCProspect.util.driverContext;
import io.cucumber.java.en.And;


public class EtapaC_DebitoStepDef extends EtapaC_DebitoAction{



    @And ("^Click on the checkbox$")
    public void AutorizaDebAutomatico() throws InterruptedException {
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driverContext.getDriver();
        js.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", chkAutorizaDebtAutom); //This is a try to click with Java
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        clickEditAutorizaDebtAutom(); // this is a default click action from framework
    }



}
```

---

**This is the code which works:**

```
package Selenium.UnitTest;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;


public class App {

    public static WebDriver driver;


    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        options.addArguments("--disable-notifications");
        // Optional, if not specified, WebDriver will search your path for chromedriver.
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "drivers\\chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options); //input objeto options na instanciação do driver
        String baseUrl = "https://salesforcerandomapp.com";
//      String tagName = "";
//      String divName = "";
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        // launch Fire fox and direct it to the Base URL
        driver.get(baseUrl);

      driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[text()='Editar']")).click();
    }

}
```

I expect that the @FindBy can find my WebElement and the framework clicks on the checkbox. This only works with this single selenium code using findElement lastly shown.